# How do I have a check constraint that refers to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, check-constraints

I have the following tables in a SQL Server 2008 db:

- **tblItem**, which has an **ItemID** field;
- **tblGoodItem**, which also has an ItemID field, and has a foreign key pointing to tblItem;
- **tblBadItem**, which also has an ItemID field, and also has a foreign key pointing to tblItem.

An item cannot be both a good item and a bad item; it must either be the one or the other. However, whether the item is good or bad, it must be an item.

My question is this: **how do I add a constraint to the ItemID fields in both tblGoodItem and tblBadItem so that an ItemID value cannot exist in both tables**?

I've read some replies in Stack Overflow on similar questions, and I'm thinking of this solution:

- Create a view **vwItem** which joins tblGoodItem on tblBadItem on ItemID.
- Write a UDF **fnItem** which does a query on vwItem to see how many records exist in the view.
- Have a constraint which calls fnItem and verifies that the value returned is 0.

Is this best idea? Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a column tblItem.ItemType column.  This column can have only one value on any given row (obviously).  Add a unique constraint over ItemID,ItemType.

Now the trick:  few people remember this, but a foreign key can reference the columns of a unique constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE tblItem (
  ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ItemType CHAR(1),
  UNIQUE KEY (ItemID, ItemType)
);

CREATE TABLE tblGoodItem (
  ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ItemType CHAR(1),
  CHECK (ItemType='G')
  FOREIGN KEY (ItemID, ItemType) REFERENCES tblItem(ItemID, ItemType) 
);

CREATE TABLE tblBadItem (
  ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY
  ItemType CHAR(1),
  CHECK (ItemType='B')
  FOREIGN KEY (ItemID, ItemType) REFERENCES tblItem(ItemID, ItemType) 
);
```

If you constrain ItemType in each of the child tables to a fixed value, then a given row in tblItem can be referenced by only one child table.

It's a three-step process to change an item from good to bad, though:

1. DELETE row from tblGoodItem
2. UPDATE row's ItemType in tblItem
3. INSERT row in tblBadItem

Comment: you beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. No need to worry about changing from bad to good - in fact, I specifically don't want such change to happen.

Answer (score 1):

get rid of tblGoodItem and tblBadItem and make a new table with a ItemType="G" or "B" and put an unique index or key on ItemID, then no constraint is needed on tblItem.

Comment: No can do, I'm afraid. Good items have some properties that bad items don't have, and vice versa.

Comment: if there are just a few, under 10 differences or so, then I's still combine them, make them allow NULL and add a check constraint to require them based on the Type column

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `SELECT` statement in a `CHECK` Constraint - thats not really what they were designed for.

I think your best option would be to write a UDF pass in the ItemId and check if it exists.  For this scenario it really is the easiest option.

I've added some test data and an example function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CheckItems(@itemId INT) RETURNS BIT

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT,
        @rv BIT


SET @i = 0

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBadItem WHERE ItemId = @ItemId) > 0
BEGIN
SET @i = 1
END


IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblGoodItem WHERE ItemId = @ItemId) > 0
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1
END

IF (@i > 1)
BEGIN
    SET @rv = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @rv =0
END


RETURN @rv

END
GO

CREATE  TABLE tblItem (
  ItemID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  DateAdded DATETIME
)
GO

CREATE TABLE tblGoodItem (
  ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  CHECK (dbo.fn_CheckItems(ItemId) = 0)

)
GO

CREATE TABLE tblBadItem (
  ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  CHECK (dbo.fn_CheckItems(ItemId) = 0)
)
GO

INSERT INTO tblItem (DateAdded)
VALUES (GETDATE())

INSERT INTO tblGoodItem(ItemID)
SELECT ItemId FROM tblItem

--This statement will fail as the ItemId is already in GoodItems
INSERT INTO tblBadItem(ItemID)
SELECT ItemId FROM tblItem


DROP TABLE tblItem
DROP TABLE tblGoodItem
DROP TABLE tblBadItem
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_CheckItems
```

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov - Could you elaborate as to why this will not work.  I have created a test and it works fine?

Comment: my apologies, I was wrong. However, such UDFs are very slow, and if you use snapshot isolation you may sporadically get wrong results under concurrency.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov - no problem.  I must admit I haven't used this whilst using snapshot replication so I couldn't disagree or agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably not understanding your business requirements here but why do you wish to have a separate table for Good and Bad items? Are these not abstractions of the same thing?

Why not use an isBadItem flag or more specifically an itemConditionStatus column.

Answer (score 1):

In tblItem, add itemType column. Have a check constraint to make sure that itemType is either good or bad. Create a unique constraint on (ItemID, itemType )

Add itemType column to both bad and good items tables. Have a check constraint to make sure that itemType is good in good table, and bad in bad table.